# UITabBar delegate method not being called (Programatically created UI)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm somewhat new at developing iOS applications, I'm creating an app but I'm not using any storyboards.

I want to use a `UITabBar`, but when I click (or tap) any item of the bar, the delegate `didSelect` method is not being called.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, this is my code:

```
class MainMenuVC: BaseVC, UITabBarDelegate {

  var tabBarMenu : UITabBar?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      self.tabBarMenu = UITabBar.init()
      self.tabBarMenu?.delegate = self;

      tabBarMenu!.items = barItems // I omitted the code to populate this array on purpose

      // Tab Style
      tabBarMenu!.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.gray
      tabBarMenu!.tintColor = Constants.Colors.gray
      tabBarMenu!.barTintColor = Constants.Colors.gray
      tabBarMenu!.isTranslucent = false
      tabBarMenu!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

      //Tab bar position
      tabBarMenu!.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.origin.x, y: contentView.frame.size.height - Constants.Dimensions.tabBarHeight, width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: Constants.Dimensions.tabBarHeight)

      // Adding
      self.view.addSubview(tabBarMenu!)
      self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tabBarMenu!)
  }

  // This is not being called
  func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
      self.handleTabBarTab(tag: item.tag)
  }
}
```

My `BaseVC` is a regular `UIViewController`, I'm not using `UITabBarViewController`

Comment: I'm not sure if `UITabBar` is intended to work without a `UITabBarController`. If you're not going to use the controller, why not just make a custom view with buttons that represent your tabs? It seems like you're just wanting to use it to receive tap events, but that's not what it's designed for. Just use `UIButton` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted here is a bit different from the code I'm actually working on.

What was actually causing trouble were some super `UIView`s where I was adding all the other views, including the `UITabBar`. These views were not enabled to user interaction.

So all I did was:

```
// Enabled the main view container to user interaction
// This was actually causing the issue
self.containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

// Adding the views
self.containerView.addSubview(tabBarMenu!)
self.containerView.bringSubviewToFront(tabBarMenu!)
```

Everything worked good after that.
So this approach is actually functional

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have an TAG for `UITabBarItem`, this works fine for me:

```
    self.tabBarMenu = UITabBar(frame: CGRect(x: contentView.frame.origin.x, y: contentView.frame.size.height - Constants.Dimensions.tabBarHeight, width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: Constants.Dimensions.tabBarHeight))
    self.tabBarMenu?.delegate = self

    let tabOneBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Test", image: nil, tag: 1)
    let tabTwoBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Test2", image: nil, tag: 2)

    tabBarMenu!.items = [tabOneBarItem, tabTwoBarItem]
```